# Why is the FXML event I'm using in my controller null?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

```
@FXML private static TextField ResponseField;
```

This is the function the "ResponseField" element is calling

```
public void GoToResultScreen() throws Exception {
        if (Character.toUpperCase(ResponseField.getText().charAt(0)) == 'N') {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WinOrLoseScreen.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = (Stage) GuideLabel.getScene().getWindow();

            stage.setTitle("Hacking Terminal");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } else if (Character.toUpperCase(ResponseField.getText().charAt(0)) == 'Y') {
            NewCard();
            TotalLabel.setText("Your total is now "+UserTotal);
        } else {
            GuideLabel.setText("Type Y or N");
        }
    }
```

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="game.blackjack.GameController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="ResponseField" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="95.0" prefHeight="178.0" prefWidth="211.0" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Fira Code Light" size="64.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="TotalLabel1" layoutX="330.0" layoutY="140.0" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="211.0" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Fira Code Light" size="64.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note: TextField elemnt with `fx:id="ResponseField"`
When I run it, I get an error because ResponseField is null
My Application class is

```
package game.blackjack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Hacking Terminal");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I ran it, and I got

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextField.getText()" because "game.blackjack.GameController.ResponseField" is null
```

I have tried checking I spelled everything right and if It is the right fxml file and controller, but it is still null.

Comment: It is not the event that is null, it is the field you have named `ResponseField` (which occurs because you defined the field as static - see the duplicate).  Additionally, please follow [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), lest you confuse readers and yourself.  Also, always provide [full stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).